# How to modify angle of Unity's transform.forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, transform

I just need to change angle of built-in transform.forward, because of moving my object straight and object has rotation on x axis. I tried multiplying transform.forward by Quaternion.Euler but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Provide the code you have tried so far, it will be easier to explain and help you.

Comment: What might be easier (code-wise) is to have your rotated object nested inside an empty Gameobject, and use the container object's `transform.forward` instead. The suitability of this solution really depends on what your situation is, though - it's hard to tell without more details (and possibly the relevant code).

Comment: @Serlite that helped, please make an answer so i can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

Try saying:

```
gameObject.transform.forward = new Vector3(1,0,0); //Whatever vector you want to use
```